# Instagram and facebook integration

Tags: android, facebook, instagram

I am trying to post a message to facebook's news feed when a user starts using my android app, without posting it to the user's wall, I noticed instagram is doing this with facebook.
I can't find anything similar to my needs in developers.facebook.com
Does anybody know how this can be done?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by posting a message to news feed but not posting to the user's wall?  Do you have a screenshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that what you are seeing is likely to be this:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/mobile-ads/

The only other way to do something similar would be to create and publish an Open Graph Action called 'started using' but I don't believe that this sort of action would be approved and anyway, it wouldn't meet your requirement of not posting to the User's timeline.

Comment: It sure give the same affect I intended